# Microsoft Bot Framework Insufficient privileges to perform this operation

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, bots, botframework

I created a Microsoft Account using my work mail.
Using this account, with 50$ credit, i tried to register my bot (already published using visual studio 2017). The problem is that when i tried to obtain the credentials for my bot, i'm getting an error that says i don't have enough privileges (even though i'm supposed to be the administrator of the account)
[Button i clicked to get credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOemb.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVh1J.png)

Comment: Can you successfully log in with your work mail on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ ?

Comment: I can log on, but i can't register anything since i get the same error (Insufficient privileges).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please log into http://aad.portal.azure.com and go to **Users and Groups** -> **User Settings** and check if **Users Can Register Applications** is set to Yes.

[image]